# Deleting google-services json file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ioexception

Actually by mistake I pasted google-services json file of another project in my current project of android .So when building the app , i get error no matching client found for package 'com.mybidu.www'. I tried to delete the file but it gives error 'Java IO Exception Cannot delete google-services.json '
Nor does it allow me to overwrite the same file . What should i do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you have to just download the new fresh google-services.json.

then copy the file.

paste it into Project view -> app folder in your android-studio app.

It will overwrite your existing file

Suppose you are not able to do it, just do this.

That json file referenced in android-studio cache so once close your android studio and then delete this file it will delete.. Hope it will help you...

Comment: thanks for the help ! i deleted all the modifications made in the gradle , rebuilt the project , than json file got deleted and readded all , correctly this time

Answer (score 8):

Open Task Manager (Press Alt + Ctr + delete) and end the running JDK process and try again the android platform removal

Answer (score 7):

Step 1. Close your Android Studio.

Step 2. Go to the location of the project.

Step 3. Delete the google-services.json

It will get deleted without any problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Delete **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'trong text** from build.gradle, sync and then delete google-services, then add again **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the fact your google-services.json file is open in any background process may be in openJDK binary which doesn't allow it to delete. 
You can solve this issue without deleting the json file rather replace the content of your old google-services.json file with the new one and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: first of all, you have to *restart* Android Studio and then you will be able to *remove* the google-service.json file in your project.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.
Close Android Studio.
Open Android Studio. 
Overwrite the file again. This time the file is not locked. And there should be no error.

Comment: Your answer is just the same as mine - Repeated answer!

Comment: The file could not be deleted in my case as you suggested, but overwriting the file fixed the problem for me.
Thanks for your feedback though.

Answer (score -1):

I suffered from that problem.
So, I get one way to solve because it will not solve by deleted from the folder.

```
Just copy all content of your new JSON file to OLD one which one not deleted

Then go to BUILD option and Click on REBUILD
```

It works for me.I hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

OpenJDK has grabbed hold of that file, and won't allow the OS to delete it.  So, you need to first kill the OpenJDK process using Task Manager.  Careful, there are two processes to kill, both starting with "OpenJDK".