# I have changed my flutter app firebase details but its still showing previous data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have this flutter app I cloned from github. It uses firebase and everything works fine. The app contains users which are already registered but I want to clear those users and use my own firebase project. All the answers I saw concerning this question did not work for me.

1. I logged in to firebase created a new project and android app.
2. Then I downloaded the google-services.json file and replaced the previous one in android/app/google-services.json

But when I reinstall the app on my android, I still see all the pre-registered users that came with the app. Please I want to clear those users and use my own empty firebase account.

Comment: Please check the issue discussed on github link https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/144  & Stackoverflow URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405126/deleting-google-services-json-file#:~:text=First%20you%20have%20to%20just,in%20your%20android%2Dstudio%20app .

Answer (score 0):

replaced new **google-services.json** is needed, but you also have to change the firebase config in the source code too, usually define in `firebase.initializeApp(config)`.

- Example config

  > ```
  > var config = {
  > apiKey: "YOUR-NEW-FIREBASE-PROJECT-API-KEY",
  > authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  > databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
  > storageBucket: "xxxxx.appspot.com"
  > };
  > ```

you can find your config in the project setting in the Firebase console.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the code that says `firebase.initializeApp(config).`

Comment: On app startup I see `import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth` then `auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();  val currentUser = auth.currentUser`

Comment: try to search for keyword “apiKey”. It should appears at least once on your project.

Comment: Not found. Actually this config details in your answer is found in the google-services.json